# Observe single event within observer single event

Tags: ios, swift, function, firebase

So essentially, I have two observeSingleEvents, one within the other, and the problem is that after the first one terminates before the second one has time to finish.The code is outlined here:

```
static func functionName(completionHandler: @escaping (_pulled: [Restaurant]?) -> Void) {
    reference.observerSinglEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //interior code
        secondReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            //interior code
            print("FIRST ALERT MESSAGE")
        })
        print("SECOND ALERT MESSAGE")
    })
 }
```

The problem here being that the `FIRST ALERT MESSAGE` is being printed AFTER the `SECOND ALERT MESSAGE`, when I need it to be printed first.

Note: I know that the code posted here makes no use of the completionHandler, I just felt that part of the function was unnecessary to the question and so I left it out.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usual as outer single observer executes first then all code inside block fires so second prints while waiting to grap first from firebase , reverse references if you want the opposite

Solution 1

```
  static func functionName(completionHandler: @escaping (_pulled: [Restaurant]?) -> Void) {
reference.observerSinglEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    //interior code
    secondReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //interior code
        print("FIRST ALERT MESSAGE")

         /// here wait by dispatch after then show second alert

          print("SECOND ALERT MESSAGE")
    })

})
```

}

Solution 2

```
static func functionName(completionHandler: @escaping (_pulled: [Restaurant]?) -> Void) {
reference.observerSinglEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    //interior code
     getFirst
     {
       print("SECOND ALERT MESSAGE -------was first")
     }
})
}
```

///

```
 func getFirst(completionHandler: @escaping (_pulled:true) -> Void) {

    secondReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //interior code
        print("FIRST ALERT MESSAGE ----- was second")
        completionHandler(true)
    })

   }
```

Comment: The only problem is that the results of the first observer is needed to call the second one (in my original case)

Comment: see if this works also edit any mistake as i'm typing without xcode , static may  cause a problem